# Restore a wallet from an external drive?

Tags: wallet, linux

I have an external drive where at some point I did a complete backup of my (linux) home directory.

There's a directory `.bitcoin`.

I now have a computer, and I just installed `bitcoin-qt` and other stuff. I started it and it generated a new receiver address.

If I copy the old `.bitcoin` directory from the external drive to my current new home, will it work?

Comment: I don't have any coins there, but I run a blog and I installed a wordpress plugin there some time ago which would publish a bitcoin address, in order to accept BTC donations. I could just change that address but I wondered.

Comment: hmmm, after my own question here http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/42773/storing-bitcoins-database-directory-on-an-external-drive I should be able to have an answer myself: actually running the whole wallet on the external DB :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid any problem,in your source computer backup your private keys

bitcoind dumpprivkey

to answer your question, By default Bitcoin will put its data here:

~/.bitcoin/

I think the wallet is located in a file wallet.dat(https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory#Linux), so if you copy it, it will works.

fore a best security level, encrypt your wallet with a paraphrase before backaping it.