# Extremely slow syncing speed while starting bitcoin-qt on HDD

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, performance

I'm sorry for adding dupelicate question (e.g. [How to speed up initial block chain sync using SSD without wasting space?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/48617/how-to-speed-up-initial-block-chain-sync-using-ssd-without-wasting-space)), but I observered a dramatical speed increase while using RAMDisk or some disk cache enhancement software (like PrimoCache).

I've enlarged database cache size up to 2048MB, it didn't seem to help. (**about 
only 2blocks/min, HDD active time 100%**)

I created a 5GB ramdisk (vs 16GB total RAM on my PC) using ImDisk, then `chainstate` was moved into this ramdisk by creating NTFS junction (`mklink /j`). After such operations, bitcoin-qt seemed to be boosted up quite a bit(**about 60 blocks/min, while HDD seemed to be quite idle**).

I wonder if there is any **smarter** way to do this? Using RAMDisk to accomplish such "boost" seemed to be too awkward.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! I see that your question states some new things but, you are right - what it asks is essentially a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

When you say smarter, you mean by not storing chainstate on a disposable drive? Unless ImDisk stores to HDD on shutdown.

Try [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/58369/sync-with-bitcoin-qt-very-slow-0-01/69862#69862).

Comment: RAMDisk is awkward, because:1.ramdisk cannot handle a power loss;2.rigid size, AFAIK, it's not easy to adjust ramdisk size with ImDisk;3.cannot apply on-the-fly, in other word, a user must get ramdisk setup work done before the daemon is started.

Comment: I've tried to read each file in chainstate once to "preheat" them into system cache, and it seemed to work.